# how to get persistent ERC sessions?

Tags: erc

I've a small problem with ERC, if I go away from keyboard for a while, it automatically disconnects the channels I've logged into and when I reopen emacs, it reconnects to the channels automatically. But I do not want this to happen. I want the erc channels to be kept alive even if I'm, away for any period of time. How can I achieve this?

ps. I'm on macOS Sierra

Comment: Is your computer going to sleep? A computer that is asleep cannot maintain any tcp connections, so your connection to the irc server would be closed.

Comment: If I stop my computer from going to sleep will it solve this problem?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Do you have access to a computer that does not go to sleep? like a personal server, or a server you pay for? If so, I would recommend ZNC. Your IRC client, ERC or whatever else you use, would connect to ZNC and ZNC would connect to your channels.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution you can use BNC proxy like [ZNC](https://wiki.znc.in/ZNC). It's a service in the middle between IRC client and networks. It will keep your connection alive so you can connect to it, read the channel history and many other features. You can install it at home or on VPS.

I use ZNC and I think it's awesome, and support is great.